# VBA - Speeding up code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that looks at data, calls out data that isn't cataloged, copies the data over to a new sheet, and deletes rows with errors. The macro runs EXTREMELY slow and I need to run it twice in order to delete the rows with errors on the new sheets. Any suggestions for how I can improve it? Thanks a bunch!

```
Sub SynthData()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lColor As Long
Dim rColored As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)

With Worksheets("Output").Columns("D")
Lastrow = .Find("*", After:=.Cells(1), _
  LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 End With
'Finds last row

For Each c In Worksheets("Output").Range("E1:E" & Lastrow)
If c.Offset(0, 1) = "#N/A" Then
  c.Interior.Color = lColor
Else: c.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If
Next c
'Highlights cells with adjacent errors

Set rColored = Nothing
For Each rCell In Worksheets("Output").Range("A1:G" & Lastrow)
    If rCell.Interior.Color = lColor Then
        If rColored Is Nothing Then
            Set rColored = rCell
        Else
            Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
        End If
    End If
Next
If rColored Is Nothing Then

   Worksheets("Source").Range("A3:G2000").ClearContents

 With Worksheets("Output").Columns("D")
   Lastrow = .Find("*", After:=.Cells(1), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 End With
  'finds last row in data

  Worksheets("Output").Range("A1:G" & Lastrow).Copy
 Worksheets("Source").Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 'copies it over

 With Worksheets("Source").Columns("F")
   lngrow = .Find("*", After:=.Cells(1), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
       For i = lngrow To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "F").Value) = "NA" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            'Deletes catalogued NAs
        End If
    Next i
  End With

   Application.CutCopyMode = False

On Error Resume Next
      If        Worksheets("source").Range("Table4[[Company]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count > 0 Then
    Worksheets("source").Range("Table4[[Company]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
'Deletes blank cells in table

    End If

  Else
    rColored.Select
    MsgBox "Selected cells contain data that are not catalogued in the refrence table. Please catalogue them before preeceding:" & _
        vbCrLf & rColored.Address
End If

Set rCell = Nothing
Set rColored = Nothing
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I do not see anything that immediately stands out - it looks like you are just processing a ton of data. However, this question may be better suited to `codereview.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Deleting rows is one of the slowest processes in Excel.  I find that sorting errors to the top or bottom of my range before deleting helps speed things up.  Are there a lot of formulas in your table, or is it hard data?

Comment: Rather then looping, use filtering and delete things in one go.  Probably can do the same w/ the coloring on the cell.

Comment: I don't see any calculations really, but if you have any in your spreadsheet, perhaps adding `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of your code, and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.

Comment: Where are we on this question, did you receive your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try disabling auto-calculation, as deleting rows will trigger all open workbooks to recalculate...

```
Dim calcMode As XlCalculation
calcMode = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'do stuff...

Application.Calculation = calcMode
```

If that doesn't help much, then look at pulling the sheet contents into an array variable and operate on that instead of the worksheet, as described [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any specific optimization,
however you might want to add before the execution:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And then reverse it at the end:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips! I sped the code up by about 50% making some of the recommended changes. The revised code is below. It still take 30 seconds+ to run though...

```
    Sub SynthData()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lColor As Long
    Dim rColored As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lngrow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

 lColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)

With Worksheets("Output").Columns("D")
   LastRow = .Find("*", After:=.Cells(1), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With
'Finds last row

For Each c In Worksheets("Output").Range("E1:E" & LastRow)
  If c.Offset(0, 1) = "#N/A" Then
    c.Interior.Color = lColor
  Else: c.Interior.Color = xlNone
  End If
Next c
'Highlights cells with adjacent errors

    Set rColored = Nothing
    For Each rCell In Worksheets("Output").Range("A1:G" & LastRow)
        If rCell.Interior.Color = lColor Then
            If rColored Is Nothing Then
                Set rColored = rCell
            Else
                Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

If rColored Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Source").Range("A3:G2000").ClearContents

    lngrow = Worksheets("Output").Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    'finds last row in data

        For i = lngrow To 1 Step -1
            If Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, "F").Value = "NA" Then
               Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                'Deletes catalogued NAs
            End If
        Next i

    LastRow = Worksheets("Output").Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    'finds last row in data

    Worksheets("Output").Range("A1:G" & LastRow).Copy
    Worksheets("Source").Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'copies it over

    On Error Resume Next
        If Worksheets("source").Range("Table4[[Company]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count > 0 Then
        Worksheets("source").Range("Table4[[Company]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        'Deletes blank cells in table
        End If

Else
    rColored.Select
    MsgBox "Selected cells contain data that are not catalogued in the refrence table. Please catalogue them before preeceding:" & _
    vbCrLf & rColored.Address
End If

Set rCell = Nothing
Set rColored = Nothing
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lColor As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim r As Integer
Dim rRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
lColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
r = 1

'Find the last row
With Worksheets("Output").Columns("D")
Lastrow = .Find("*", After:=.Cells(1), _
  LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 End With


'Highlight cells with adjacent errors
For Each c In Worksheets("Output").Range("E1:E" & Lastrow)
    If Application.IsNumber(c.Offset(0, 1)) Then
        GoTo Continue1
    Else
        If c.Offset(0, 1) = "#N/A" Then
            For Each c2 In Worksheets("output").Range("A" & c.Row & ":G" & c.Row)
            c2.Interior.Color = lColor
            Next c2
        Else: c.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
Continue1:
    End If
Next c


' Add a sheet called OutputTemp and copy the values from the worksheet Output
Application.Sheets.Add
With Application.ActiveSheet
    .Name = "OutputTemp"
    Application.Sheets("Output").Cells.Copy
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    '.Range("B1").Value = Me.DTPicker10.Value
End With

'audit the worksheet called OutputTemp and delete any lines with errors
For r = 1 To Lastrow
    Set rRange = Application.Worksheets("OutputTemp").Range("E" & r & ":E" & r)
    If Application.IsNumber(rRange.Offset(0, 1)) Then
        GoTo Continue2
    Else
        If rRange.Offset(0, 1) = "#N/A" Then
            rRange.EntireRow.Delete
            r = r - 1
        End If
Continue2:
    End If

Next r


'Clear previous contents of the worksheet called Source and then copy the data from OutputTemp
Worksheets("Source").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("OutputTemp").Range("A1:G" & Lastrow).Copy
Worksheets("Source").Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Delete the worksheet called OutputTemp
Worksheets("OutputTemp").Delete
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```